# ckeditor get element by id

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

What I am try to achieve is to insert some content in a specific container element designated by a unique id. This would help me insert content at positions other than cursor positions.

`editor.model.insertContent(modelFragment);` is a function that would insert the new fragment at the cursor position, the second parameter that would be accepted is [selectable](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-insertContent) which I am not sure how to specify to match to that particular div id.

When I was googling for the same, I found a [desirable method](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-findOne) in ckeditor4, but unfortunately I am looking for an option in ckeditor5.